# find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n+1}(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n+1}(n+1)}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n+1}(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{16^{n}\cdot4(n+1)}$$

is it enough to say that the limit is 0?

Comment: Note that $4^{2n+1}\not=16^{n+1}$ and that $4^{2n+1}=4\cdot 16^n$.

Comment: @mathlove right, edited

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{16^n\cdot(4(n+1))}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{16^n}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4(n+1)}$$

As $|\frac{-10}{16}|<1$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-10)^n}{16^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\frac{-10}{16}\bigr)^n=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4(n+1)}=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{1+0}=0$$

I think this is right. forgive me if i'm wrong I'm also just learning limits.